# Can Google Calendar connect to a CalDAV server?

Tags: google-calendar

I know events added in Google Calendar can be accessed in other applications (e.g. iCal) by connecting to Google's CalDAV server. But I have my own CalDAV server to which people add events with a variety of applications, and I was wondering whether Google Calendar can automatically import (and stay in sync) with these events, presumably by connecting to my CalDAV server? I can't find any reference to this in Google's help pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this has been requested as a feature, suggesting you can't: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=34e8c4dc6379472d&hl=en

Comment: Does someone knows if this is doable now in 2019. It seems google closed the feature request, but I don't think this is possible today.